# Can anybody help me to solve the problem which is about the "super" in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

The "super" part I'm not very clear in Java, so how can I code it?

```
public class AggressiveAlien extends Alien
{

public AggressiveAlien(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister)
{
 super(currentLocation, energyCanister);
}

public int collectCanister(NormalPlanet canister)
{
 super.collectCanister(canister);
 n=1;
}

private boolean attack(int lifePoints)
{
 boolean attack;
 if (AggresiveAlien.currentLocation() = Alien.getOtherAlien())
 {
  AggresiveAlien.energyCanisters = (int) (1/2) * Alien.energyCanisters + AggresiveAlien.energyCanisters;
  lifePoints = lifePoints - 1;
  attack = true;
 }
 return attack;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is correct, provided that the `Alien` class has a constructor with the signature:

```
public Alien(XYCoordination, int)
```

Specifically,

```
super(currentLocation, energyCanister);
```

means, before you run this constructor run the constructor for the immediate superclass passing it the `currentLocation` and `energyCanister` values.  Note that every constructor (apart for the `Object` constructor) chains to a superclass constructor, either explicitly or implicitly.

---

However, the following is probably incorrect:

```
AggresiveAlien.currentLocation()
```

That requires `currentLocation()` to be a static method, and that would imply that all instances of a `AggresiveAlien` have the same location ... which doesn't make a lot of sense.  In fact, I think the method needs to be an instance method, and the call would therefore have to be:

```
this.currentLocation()
```

or just

```
currentLocation()
```

You have made this mistake in a number of places.

Answer (score 1):

It means "call the version of this method (or constructor) that's defined in the immediate superclass".